# How to crawl the whole website, if data append with Javascript after scrolling

Tags: web-crawler

I need to crawl a website, but the problem is, there is no linked pagination at the bottom. Data appends if you scroll to the bottom. Now how can I make this happen with my crawler? Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try examining the script that executes to append the data when you scroll down.  It must retrieve the additional data somehow -- just see what it's doing, and have your crawler do the same thing.

Comment: how google manages this ? google cannot examine the whole script, there should be another way out, but i will try your solution thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a robot like Selenium could work, you can simulate a real user in a real navigator. One thing I did with facebook once was to use a JavaScript interpreter in C++/Qt and then send request via it. A lot faster than Selenium.

I'm sure Google has a lot more processing power than you do, and webmaster do everything they can to be parsed by them.